Column entity alignment with 'align' does not align left or does not want to connect with other columns
I've been trying to play around with this for way too long now, so I decided to post the question here.
The reason why I am doing it with 'align' is because I want equations to be numbered accordingly in the document. The initial problem I had is that the entities of the first column align to the right of the column but I want them to be aligned left (to the red line) The code shows why and how:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
    \hspace{6pt}\mathbf{\hat{M}} &= \mathbf{T^T M T} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        x \\ x
    \end{bmatrix} && \\
    \mathbf{\hat{K}} &= \mathbf{T^T K T} && \\
    \mathbf{\widehat{f}} &= \mathbf{T^T f_m} && \\
    \mathbf{\hat{u}} &= \text{the reduced system's displacement vector} && \\
    \mathbf{\hat{\ddot{u}}} &= \text{the reduced system's acceleration vector} &&
\end{flalign}

\end{document}


Whenever I use the following code the first column does align to the left but there is no way I can move the part from '=' onwards to the left and attach it like it is in the first picture.
Where:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
    &\hspace{6pt}\mathbf{\hat{M}}&&= \mathbf{T^T M T} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        x \\ x
    \end{bmatrix} & \\
    &\hspace{6pt}\mathbf{\hat{K}} &&= \mathbf{T^T K T} & \\
    &\hspace{6pt}\mathbf{\widehat{f}} &&= \mathbf{T^T f_m} & \\
    &\hspace{6pt}\mathbf{\hat{u}} &&= \text{the reduced system's displacement vector} & \\
    &\hspace{6pt}\mathbf{\hat{\ddot{u}}} &&= \text{the reduced system's acceleration vector} &
\end{flalign}

\end{document}


Is there someone with ideas or a solution for this?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

fo all AMS alignments the colums alternate between right and left alignment so if you want to start with left alignment you need that text in column two and have an empty cell at the start of each row.

How can I make it compilable? Sorry I am new here

your examples hould start \documentclass have \usepackage{amsmath} and end \end{document} so people can actually use the code posted to see the problem and test answers

Should be good now! Thank you

flalign is "full length align" so explicitly designed to stretch out the columns as you show.  You don't want extra space so use alignat not align.
Personally I would not left align the first cell as it means giving up natural spacing around the = (or giving up alignment on =) but if you do want that, then the usual rules apply: Odd columns right align, even columns left align.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{4}
    &\mathbf{\hat{M}} &&= \mathbf{T^T M T} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        x \\ x
    \end{bmatrix} &&& \\
    &\mathbf{\hat{K}} &&= \mathbf{T^T K T} && \\
    &\mathbf{\widehat{f}} &&= \mathbf{T^T f_m} && \\
    &\mathbf{\hat{u}} &&= \text{the reduced system's displacement vector} && \\
    &\mathbf{\hat{\ddot{u}}} &&= \text{the reduced system's acceleration vector} &&
\end{alignat}

\end{document}


I agree with the '=' ideology, however, for now, I want it to be consistent with the rest of the document. I tried myself with 3 columns, not 4. Thankyou for that. What is the easiest way to align this to the left side of the page?

@Rellic you can use \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

You don't need flalign if all your equations should be at the left margin.
Here are three proposals, the middle one is, in my opinion, better, because it links the descriptions to the main equation. The bottom one is typographically dubious.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\newcommand{\vm}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\setlength{\mathindent}{6pt} % all equations start 6pt from the margin

\begin{document}

We have a big equation involving vectors and matrices and this
description will fill two lines
\begin{equation}
\hat{\vm{M}}=\vm{T}^T \vm{M} \vm{T}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
\hat{\vm{M}} &= \vm{T}^T \vm{M} \vm{T} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ x \end{bmatrix} \\
\hat{\vm{K}} &= \vm{T}^T \vm{K} \vm{T} \\
\hat{\vm{f}} &= \vm{T}^T \vm{f}_{m} \\
\hat{\vm{u}} &= \text{the reduced system's displacement vmor} \\
\hat{\ddot{\vm{u}}} &= \text{the reduced system's acceleration vmor}
\end{align}

\begin{subequations}\label{bigeq}
We have a big equation involving vectors and matrices and this
description will fill two lines
\begin{equation}
\hat{\vm{M}}=\vm{T}^T \vm{M} \vm{T} \tag{\ref{bigeq}}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
\hat{\vm{M}} &= \vm{T}^T \vm{M} \vm{T} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ x \end{bmatrix} \\
\hat{\vm{K}} &= \vm{T}^T \vm{K} \vm{T} \\
\hat{\vm{f}} &= \vm{T}^T \vm{f}_{m} \\
\hat{\vm{u}} &= \text{the reduced system's displacement vmor} \\
\hat{\ddot{\vm{u}}} &= \text{the reduced system's acceleration vmor}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

We have a big equation involving vectors and matrices and this
description will fill two lines
\begin{equation}
\hat{\vm{M}}=\vm{T}^T \vm{M} \vm{T}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\hat{\vm{M}} &&= \vm{T}^T \vm{M} \vm{T} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ x \end{bmatrix} \\
&\hat{\vm{K}} &&= \vm{T}^T \vm{K} \vm{T} \\
&\hat{\vm{f}} &&= \vm{T}^T \vm{f}_{m} \\
&\hat{\vm{u}} &&= \text{the reduced system's displacement vmor} \\
&\hat{\ddot{\vm{u}}} &&= \text{the reduced system's acceleration vmor}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}


If your equation are centered, you can use nccmath that provides a fleqn environment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\newcommand{\vm}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{bigeq}
We have a big equation involving vectors and matrices and this
description will fill two lines
\begin{equation}
\hat{\vm{M}}=\vm{T}^T \vm{M} \vm{T} \tag{\ref{bigeq}}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{fleqn}[6pt]
\begin{align}
\hat{\vm{M}} &= \vm{T}^T \vm{M} \vm{T} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ x \end{bmatrix} \\
\hat{\vm{K}} &= \vm{T}^T \vm{K} \vm{T} \\
\hat{\vm{f}} &= \vm{T}^T \vm{f}_{m} \\
\hat{\vm{u}} &= \text{the reduced system's displacement vmor} \\
\hat{\ddot{\vm{u}}} &= \text{the reduced system's acceleration vmor}
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}

You can use the alignat method, if you so prefer.

I changed the syntax used: every variable should be an argument to its own \vm command (vector or matrix; use a different name, if you wish) and \hat should be outside.

Thank you for the options! Clear explanation!
